# How to make MultipartBbody.Part request from cache image using retrofit

Tags: android, image, retrofit2, multipart

My image is cached at located:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.example.muhammadusman.project/cache/cropped1340954678061130725.jpg
```

how can i make the Multipart.body request for this interface:

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("/image/{name}")
    Call<Recognition> recognizeImage(
            @Path("name")String name,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

**Input to the Function**

```
key="40"

imageName="cropped1340954678061130725.jpg"

path="file:///data/user/0/com.example.muhammadusman.project/cache/cropped1340954678061130725.jpg"
```

**This is My Code:** i am using this code to make the MultipartBody.Part object. But i am not able to make the object. Always program crash.

```
 public static MultipartBody.Part creatPartFromPath(String key,String imageName,String path){

        File file=new File(path);
        String mediaType= getMimeType(path);
        RequestBody intermediateFile=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mediaType),file);
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(key,imageName,intermediateFile);
    }

  public static String getMimeType(String url) {

        return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Github link for source code:**
https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java

**Use this code:**

i have test this code this works fine. The link contain the whole source code. But i customize the file for you this will work fine for you.

**Problem Solution:**

```
 String path=FileUtils1.getPath(getContext(),titleImageUri);
```

now you path will be

```
path="/data/user/0/com.example.muhammadusman.project/cache/cropped8174258068738559892.jpg"
```

replace your previous path with this new path.

```
public class FileUtils1 {
    private FileUtils1() {} //private constructor to enforce Singleton pattern

    /** TAG for log messages. */
    static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false; // Set to true to enable logging

    public static final String MIME_TYPE_AUDIO = "audio/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_TEXT = "text/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_IMAGE = "image/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_VIDEO = "video/*";
    public static final String MIME_TYPE_APP = "application/*";

    public static final String HIDDEN_PREFIX = ".";


    public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
        if (url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        if (DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG + " File -",
                    "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                            ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                            ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                            ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                            ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                            ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                            ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
            );

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider

            // ExternalStorageProvider
             if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```